# Google not indexing new posts quickly

Tags: indexing

Hi I have a popular blog built with WordPress, Google used to index new posts fairly quickly, at least within 12 hours, but now it's not indexing new posts before more than 2 days, anything I can do to make it faster? I am concerned because some of the posts are news so they quickly lose their value if not indexed.

Comment: Patience is the key to success.

Comment: Not really a helpful answer, other blogs are indexed within a few hours, there is some issue with mine and I'm trying to discover what I might have done wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i said '**Patience is the key to success.**'

```
<meta name="revisit-after" content="7 days" />
```

Sign up here ([Google Webmastertool](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/?hl=en)) and submit your sitemap (again).

in Google Webmastertool you can see any crawler errors, blocked urls and much more. Just check it out!

Good luck.

Comment: should I add that meta to my page or?

Comment: ok I'm adding it. However if currently posts are added with a delay of two days, how will that help? I am assuming it instructs spiders to visit every 7 days.

Comment: seems to be irrelevant http://www.seomoz.org/q/meta-revisit